# Removing need for passphrase key in Google Cloud Projects

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, google-chrome-os

I am trying to set up datalab notebooks in a Google Cloud project. I screwed up and entered a passphrase during the first

```
$ datalab connect INSTANCE_NAME
```

install.I quickly realized that I wished I hadn't done that, so I deleted the instance and tried to reinstall. It asked again.
So, I did a bit of googling (after just deleting the new project and creating a new one), and discovered that the passphrase is required across projects.

So, I went to the metadata tab and deleted it through there- but it comes back whenever I try and create an instance (on any project) through the terminal.

Ok. So, I tried using gcloud to change the instance to not need the project passphrase, using

```
$ cloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] --metadata block-project-ssh-keys=TRUE
```

Same thing.

Please, what the heck am I missing? How do I just permanently remove the need for a passphrase when setting up an instance in datalab from the ssh terminal?

I wouldn't mind using the passphrase so much, but whenever I enter it, the terminal just stops (not hard stop- it just sits there without processing until I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and force stop. I can type and enter and whatever, but it doesn't register my passphrase.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, I am setting all this up using a stock Pixelbook. That shouldn't matter since everything is through Google Cloud, but there ya go.

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen other, similar question where they suggest deleting the swapfile...but I have no idea how to do that. I am a Google Cloud beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passphrase isn't tied to your GCP project or Datalab instances in any way.

Instead, it is a property of your local private SSH key. This file usually winds up under `~/.ssh` and is named something like `google_compute_engine`.

Since you mention using a Pixelbook, I assume you are running the `datalab connect` command from Cloud Shell. In that case, this file is stored inside of your Cloud Shell instance.

Delete that file, and then the next run of `datalab connect` will generate a new one (for which you can leave the passphrase empty).